# Word problem number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The number of the students of one school is a natural number that is between $600$ and $500$.

If we were to divide the students into $20$ groups or $12$ groups or $36$ groups, we get a remainder of $7$ in every time.

What is the number of students in this schooL?

I'm sure it will be $k\text{lcm}(20,12,36)$ where $k$ is an integer which will turn out to be $3$ and so the number of students in this school is $3\text{lcm}(20,12,36)+7=3\cdot180+7=540+7=547$ but what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: You're *sure* of it, but you don't know the reasoning behind it?

Comment: You nailed it...

Comment: Yes because this is from a elementary number theory book and before this exercise there was a discussion of lcm, and gcd will not give me a big value so I tried lcm and it worked.

Comment: We can safely avoid CRT as the remainders are same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we had $7$ students less, the number of students would have been divisible by $12,20,36$ separately.

Now by definition, LCM is the smallest positive integer which is divisible by a given set of numbers

So, here the smallest positive integer  will be lcm$(12,36,20)=180$

So, the required number will be of the form $180k+7$ where $k$ is any integer

We need $500<180k+7<600\iff 2<k<4\implies k=?$ as $k$ is an integer

Comment: Gorgeous! Absolutely gorgeous!

Comment: You're using the fact that the LCM divides every common multiple, aren't you?

Comment: @JackM, Yes, as LCM is the smallest one positive

Comment: @labbhattacharjee This is a nitpick, but that doesn't follow directly, does it? I mean, I agree that the LCM divides every common multiple, but you can't deduce that instantly from the fact that it's the smallest one, can you?

Comment: @JackM, What is the definition of LCM. Here lcm$(12,36,20)=$lcm$(2^2\cdot3,2^2\cdot3^2,2^2\cdot5)=2^{\text{max}(2,2,2)}\cdot3^{\text{max}(1,2,0)}\cdot5^{\text{max}(0,0,1)}=180$

Comment: Excellent explanation.